# How do I get and set a Svelte store value from a web page where I injected a Svelte app?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-store

I built a Svelte app which includes a stores.js file containing a writable store value called sSchool. I inject the app in my html page this way.

```
<div id="app-container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'choice/svelte/public/build/bundle.js' %}"></script>
<script>
  var myapp= new app({
    "target": document.getElementById("app-container"),
  })
</script>
```

I'd like to be able to get and set the store value sSchool from JavaScript snippets inside this webpage. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1st thing you need to figure out is how to get the reference of your `sSchool` store.

---

1 suggestion would be to expose it the same way you expose the `app` class, which i believe you are doing something like this somewhere?

```js
import App from './App.svelte';
window.app = App;
```

maybe you could have

```js
import sStore from './store.js';
window.sStore = sStore;
```

with that, you could get the value of the store by subscribing to it

```js
sStore.subscribe(value => {
  console.log('store value:', value);
});
```

and setting the value of the store

```js
sStore.set(newValue);
```

---

Another approach would be to define component methods in your `app` component:

```
<script>
   import sStore from './store.js';
   
   export function setStoreValue(newValue) {
     $sStore = newValue;
   }
   export function getStoreValue() {
     return $sStore;
   }
</script>
```

then in your script,

```html
<script>
  var myapp= new app({
    "target": document.getElementById("app-container"),
  })

  myapp.setStoreValue(123);
  myApp.getStoreValue(); // 123
</script>
```

**References**

- Watch my video "How to call functions inside a component" https://youtu.be/EA0EX3tbNNM, which explained how to call functions inside a component

Comment: Thank you! I used the second approach "define component methods in your app component" and it worked.